# Как проверить слово на отсутствие смешивания кириллицы и латинского алфавита?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Проверка слова на отсутствие смешивания кириллицы и латинского алфавита. Вопрос заключается в том, как можно производить проверку текста (текст из БД), чтобы в одном слове не было букв латинского и русского алфавита?

Например "o [ou], p [pi:], c [si:], a [ei]" не заменяли аналогичные буквы русского алфавита и слово "горох" не было введено "гo([ou])pox", также в обратную сторону английское слово не должно содержать русских букв.

P.S. изначально не известно перед проверкой на каком языке написано слово, т.е. необходимо проверить, если ли в слове сочетания букв из двух разных алфавитов.

Comment: Приведите примеры входных данных и результат, который вы хотите получить для этих данных. И укажите в вопросе с чем именно у вас возникли трудности в реализации

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проверка на то, все ли буквы из латинского алфавита:

```
import string

def all_en(word):
    if all(c in string.ascii_letters for c in word):
        return True
    return False
```

Такая же проверка на русские буквы может быть разной, в зависимости от того, могут ли в словах быть цифры и прочие знаки (подчеркивание, например).

Можно, например, просто проверять, находится ли код символа в нужном диапазоне. Для UTF-8 можно использовать такой вариант:

```
def all_ru(word):
    for letter in word:
        if ord(letter) < 1040 or ord(letter) > 1103:
            return False
    return True
```

1040 - 1103 (0x410 - 0x44f) это диапазон кодов для русского алфавита (без "Ёё"). Для ё/Ё нужно еще добавить проверку на равенство 1025 или 1105 (0x401 / 0x451):

```
def all_ru(word): # немного оптимизировал еще тут
    for letter in word:
        code = ord(letter)
        if not(1040 < code < 1103) and code != 1025 and code != 1105:
            return False
    return True
```

Ну и то, что вам нужно, в итоге таким образом:

```
def contains_en_and_ru(word):
    if not all_ru(word) and not all_en(word):
        return True # есть латинские и кириллица
    return False # только латинские или только кириллица
```

Comment: UTF-8, 
изначально не известно перед проверкой на каком языке написано слово, т.е. необходимо проверить есть ли в слове сочетания букв из двух разных алфавитов

Answer (score 4):

Создать словари с похожими по написанию буквами

```
RU = ['а', 'с', 'е', 'р', 'х', 'о', ]
EN = ['a', 'c', 'e', 'p', 'x', 'o', ]
```

```
>>> ru == en
False
```

и проверять через функции, например:

```
def ru_only(word):
    for e in EN:
        if e in word:
            return False
    return True


def en_only(word):
    for r in RU:
        if r in word:
            return False
    return True
```

результат - True или False:

```
word = 'горox'    # половина слова - кириллицей
>>> en_only(word)
False
>>> ru_only(word)
False

word = 'gopox'    # всё латинскими
>>> en_only(word)
True
>>> ru_only(word)
False

word = 'горох'    # всё кириллицей
>>> en_only(word)
False
>>> ru_only(word)
True
```

Comment: prin, trin, ... литин 

Comment: @TigerTV.ru ааа... а я все думаю, что за "литин" такой ;)

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробoвать так

```py
def has_mix(word):
    if len(word) == 0:
        return False
    page = ord(word[0]) & 0x1fff00 
    return not all(map(lambda x: ord(x) & 0x1fff00 == page, word))

ss = ["hello", "helloумир", "привет"]
for s in ss:
    print(s, ":", has_mix(s))
```

Вывод:

```
hello : False
helloумир : True
привет : False
```

можно упростить и проверять один бит

```py
def has_mix(word):
    if len(word) == 0:
        return False
    page = ord(word[0]) & 0x400 
    return not all(map(lambda x: ord(x) & 0x400 == page, word))
```

Comment: а как оно работает?

Comment: @Эникейщик, ord возвращает код в [таблице](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block), сначала определяется кодовая подтаблица первого символа(с помощью побитового &), а затем уже идет проверка других символов на вхождение в эту подтаблицу.